# Save GridView Values back to database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, gridview

I have the following situation:

I pass values from one GridView1 to another (GridView2) These values are rows which were selected in GridView1. Then with a foreach loop I change all values in a certain column from "0" to "1" (in GridView2). This works and it's shown in my GridView2. Now the problem is: How can I write these values back into the database without using the "Update" method?. Because it shouldn't be necessary for the SQL Adapter to check which values were changed because it's clear in this case.

Comment: Why would you want to not use the `Update` method or let the SQLAdapter do what it was designed for?

Comment: because I'm currently working with a database that has no primary key. I would like to try it. So is there a possibility to do that without the Update method? and second question: How would one do it with Update?

Comment: How would you know which record to update, if there is no primary key? The SQL that you would use to update each record can be used in the Update method instead. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, but if you must, iterate through the DS, use the SqlCommand type to call an update SQL with the values

Comment: I just thought I can do it without Update because he shall update every value in a certain column which is displayed in my GridView2. So it's not neessary to search which values are being updated or is it?

Comment: You will need to know which rows have to be updated, which columns needs to be updated will depend on your requirements for the changes.